# Iterating through a two dimensional std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have defined a 2d map as follows:

```cpp
unordered_map< string, unordered_map<string, Road*>* > matrix;
```

Where road is simply:

```cpp
class Road {
public:
    Road() : connected(0), weight(0) {}

    bool connected;
    int weight;
};
```

I've tried iterating through the map this way, but it failed to compile.

```cpp
    for (auto &i : matrix) {
        for (unordered_map< string, unordered_map<string, Road*>* >::iterator iter1 = i.second->begin();
             iter1 != i.second->end(); iter1++) {

        }
    }
```

Since I know my matrix is always NxN, one thing I can do is

```cpp
    for (auto &i : matrix) {
        for (auto &j : matrix) {

        }
    }
```

But i was wondering if there is a cleaner approach with varying size.

Comment: Your second example doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: "but it failed to compile". Thanks for this detailed and useful problem statement...

Comment: `auto` type isn't an iterator.

Comment: Why the use of pointers here? I don't see a need for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over maps and unordered maps yields key/value pairs. When you do

```
for (const auto& p : matrix)
    ...
```

the variable `p` has type `const std::pair<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, Road*>*>&`. Therefore, to iterate over the inner map, do:

```
for (const auto& p : matrix)
    for (const auto& q : *p.second) {
        Road *r = q.second;
        ...
    }
```

You can use `p.first` to get the outer key, and `q.first` to get the inner key.

Answer (score 1):

The sizes of the containers doesn't matter. The range-for loops (when used correctly) will work for containers of any size even in your nested case.